# What is the differrence between mysql.innodb_table_stats and information_schema.innodb_tablestats?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, information-schema

I am using `mysql-8.0.19`. I want to find a way to detect changes in database tables. E.g. compare the value of a query to the value of the last query.

I see that there exist two tables from which I could obtain table change information:

`informatin_schema.innodb_tablestats` with columns:

```
TABLE_ID
NAME
STATS_INITIALIZED
NUM_ROWS
CLUST_INDEX_SIZE
OTHER_INDEX_SIZE
MODIFIED_COUNTER
AUTOINC
REF_COUNT
```

`mysql.innodb_table_stats` with columns:

```
database_name
table_name
last_update
n_rows
clustered_index_size
sum_of_other_index_sizes
```

My questions are:

- Why there exist two tables with similar information?
- Which table should I use to obtain update information?

Comment: [`mysql.innodb_table_stats`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html) is static persistent statistic table. [`information_schema.innodb_tablestats`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-innodb-tablestats-table.html) is temporary dynamic (obtained from from in-memory data) statistic table. These table are not analogs. *I want to find a way to detect changes in database tables.* Use service table and triggers.

Comment: @Akina Where is `service` table located? I cannot find it neither in `mysql` nor in `information_schema`. Regarding triggers. I'm not supposed to change anything in the database server.

Comment: *Where is service table located?* You must create it. It is common table in the database for storing different service information not related to the data itself but related to processes flow, flags/constants values, etc. Similar to application settings stored in INI files or in registry...